# Abortar fetch al desmontar un componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Tengo el siguiente problema con mi app hecha en React.

Tengo un `component` (Component1) el cual en su ciclo de vida `componentDidMount` hace un `fetch` a una `api` la cual con el `response` actualiza el `state` de ese mismo componente, todo esto bajo una llamada `async` usando `promises`. Resulta que al hacer `render` del componente de nombre Component1 se ejecutaba el `fetch` pero la `promise` no ah sido resuelta aun, en ese momento hago `render` de otro componente (Component2, cambio de pagina) desmontando el Component1. Todo bien hasta ahí.

Pero en mi consola del browser tengo un warning que me indica que debo eliminar la subscripcion de las llamadas `async`

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Código de ejemplo:

```
componentDidMount () {
this.setState({ isLoading: true })

window.fetch(URL_FETCH).then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(jsonStr => {
      const { datum } = jsonStr
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({monitoring: datum, isLoading: false})
      }, 1000)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Respuesta de red OK.')
    this.setState({monitoring: [], isLoading: false, isError: true})
  }
})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message)
    this.setState({monitoring: [], isLoading: false, isError: true})
  })
}
```

¿Como puedo resolver mi problema?

...Ok ! Esta bien, el `setTimeout` esta resuelto. Solo persiste el problema para abortar el `this.setState()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfecto !

El problema lo resolví de la siguiente forma.

Dentro de mi clase y antes de mi `componentDidMount` cree una instancia de la `api` `AbortController` de la siguiente forma.

```
abortController = new AbortController()
```

Despues a mi `fetch` le pase un nuevo parametro en la llamada.

```
window.fetch(MI_URL, { signal: this.abortController.signal }).then.....
```

Finalmente en el ciclo de vida del desmontado (`componentWillUnmount`) use lo siguiente.

```
this.abortController.abort()
```

Dejo el código completo a continuación.

```
abortController = new AbortController()

componentDidMount () {
this.setState({ isLoading: true })

window.fetch(MI_URL, { signal: this.abortController.signal }).then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then(jsonStr => {
      const { datum } = jsonStr
      this.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({monitoring: datum, isLoading: false})
      }, 1000)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Respuesta de red OK.')
    this.setState({monitoring: [], isLoading: false, isError: true})
  }
})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message)
    this.setState({monitoring: [], isLoading: false, isError: true})
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.abortController.abort()
}
```

Espero que ah alguien más le pueda servir esto ! (:

**PD**: Una vez cancelado el `TimeOut` no deberia haber problemas con el `this.setState()` en caso contrario usar la `api` de `AbortController`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la API de AbortController
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch

```
this.abortController = new AbortController();

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(URL_FETCH, { signal: this.abortController.signal }) // Pasas signal como segundo parámetro
  ...
}

// En componentWillUnmount llamas al método abort() del AbortController
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.abortController.abort();
}
```

Comment: Es la misma respuesta que di a mi pregunta.